# How do I delete the first character on a string? [Lua]

Tags: string, lua, trim

Basically, I have a string in Lua, which is a user output, but I want to trim the first character cause I don't really need it. How can I do that?

Comment: `str = str:sub(2)`

Comment: Open the Lua manual, there is a chapter called "string manipulation". Sounds promissing right ? :)  Please read manuals prior to asking questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot delete the first character of a string.

But you can copy a substring that starts from the second character using string.sub

> **string.sub(s, i [,j])**
>
> Returns the substring of s that starts at i and continues until j; i
> and j can be negative. If j is absent, then it is assumed to be equal
> to -1 (which is the same as the string length)....

So `str = str:sub(2)` will give you the substring of `str` that starts at character `2` which is what you want.